# Problem regarding Linklist in PHP. I'm traversing the data value in the linklist, i'm getting the duplicated values i do not know why

Tags: php, data-structures

when I run this code and trying to traverse the data field in Node it gives me duplicated values I do not know why. is anybody has any idea why I am getting these duplicated values...
Thanks in advance for your valuable input

```
<?php function linkedListMultiplierCheck( $arr, $init ) {
  $head = new Node($arr[0],
                   new Node($arr[1],
                            new Node($arr[2],
                                     new Node($arr[3], NULL))));

  return linkedListMultiplier($head, $init);
}

class Node {
  public $data, $next;
  public function __construct($data, $next = NULL) {
    list($this->data, $this->next) = [$data, $next];
      
  }
}

// DO NOT MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE                           
                              
function linkedListMultiplier($head, $init)
{
foreach ($head["data"] as $value) {
    if($head["next"]==null){
        $total = $total+1;
    }
}

    $t = $head;
    $k=0;
    $init =2;
    while ($t->data){
        $temp=$t->data;
        print_r($temp . "    ");
        if (!$t->next) {
            $t->next = new Node(0);
        }            
   
        $t = $t->next;
    
    };
    return $head;
}

$head=linkedListMultiplierCheck([2, 3,4,5], 1);
linkedListMultiplier($head,1);
?>
```

when I run this code I am getting values like

```
2    3    4    5    2    3    4    5
```

I do not know why it is duplicated the values it should only give me like the bellow

```
2    3    4    5
```

Comment: You're running `linkedListMultiplier` twice, once in `linkedListMultiplierCheck` and once directly. For each run, `print_r` is called once per node, so each node is printed twice.

Comment: where i am running twice? if you see the first ''' linkedListMultiplierCheck ''' is making the linklist and this other ''' linkedListMultiplierCheck ''' i need to multiple with linklist some values but the problem is i am not getting this data current when i traverse it give me wrong answer. because i can not traverse it correctly @Welbog